# Laravel 4 subdomain routing for something.* instead of *.something

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, I can route wildcard subdomains like *.example.com like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.example.com'), function()
```

I have a different (inverse) use case. We provide a whitelabeled service, and the admin is at `admin.example.com`, where `example.com` could be any of the whitelabeled domains.

Unfortunately, the domain wildcard appears to stop on `.` characters, so this doesn't work:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'admin.{domain}'), function()
```

This works, but feels hacky (and breaks down if we're ever asked to run on `admin.subdomain.example.com`:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'admin.{domain}.{tld}'), function()
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue when the customer provides a ccTLD like `admin.domain.com.uk`.

The only workaround at the moment is to setup multiple groups covering all the different possibilities.

I'm working on a patch to allow multiples options, there is also an open [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7306) to  add support for optional placeholders in the host. You are welcomed to share your use use case there as well.